# I cant overwrite on the attributes in responsive unless I create a new class in the tag

Tags: html, css

i should create a class in tag h2 for work the attribute in responsive ,
i dont know where is the problem , is this something about the browser
[this is my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kKLZd.jpg)

i think it should be work normally without create a class in tag html

Comment: are you sure you are testing it with a window with a max width of 767 pixels?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see that you have the media query on line 162 and the same class without the media query on line 167.

You need to put media queries at the bottom of the stylesheet, or at least below the same classes that are within the media queries.

CSS is read from top to bottom.

Everything that is below some other CSS will overwrite what's on top of it.

You can still use !important at the end of the CSS properties within the media query to make it overwrite everything else.